# DataLoader default_collate found "NoneType"

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I have a dataset directory that has hundreds of subdirectories, each subdirectory's name is a UUID. Inside each subdirectory, there are four files: an image (`png`), a `html`, a `json`, and a `txt` file.

The image, html, and txt form the sample, and the json contains the corresponding label.

Here's the `__getitem__()` function of the `Dataset` subclass that I defined:

```py
def __getitem__(self, idx):
        ID = self.list_IDs[idx]
        label = self.labels[ID]

        # load the sample
        html = open(os.path.join(DATA_PATH, ID, 'html_dirty.html'),
                    encoding='utf-8').read()
        url = open(os.path.join(DATA_PATH, ID, 'url.txt'),
                   encoding='utf-8').read()

        sample = {'html': html, 'url': url}

        if self.load_img:
            sample['img'] = cv2.imread(os.path.join(DATA_PATH, ID, 'ss.png'))

        return sample, label
```

But when I run:

```py
x = CustomDataset(partitions['train'], labels) # partitions['train'] is just a list of UUIDs 
train_generator = DataLoader(x, batch_size=32) 
for i, batch in enumerate(train_generator):
    print(i)
```

It errors out. Here's the full stack trace:

```py
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Work\ml-project-1\data_loader.py", line 67, in <module>
    for i, batch in train_generator:
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Work\ml-project-1\ml_proj_env\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 628, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Work\ml-project-1\ml_proj_env\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 671, in _next_data
    data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Work\ml-project-1\ml_proj_env\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py", line 61, in fetch
    return self.collate_fn(data)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Work\ml-project-1\ml_proj_env\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\collate.py", line 271, in default_collate
    return collate(batch, collate_fn_map=default_collate_fn_map)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Work\ml-project-1\ml_proj_env\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\collate.py", line 147, in collate
    return [collate(samples, collate_fn_map=collate_fn_map) for samples in transposed]
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Work\ml-project-1\ml_proj_env\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\collate.py", line 147, in <listcomp>
    return [collate(samples, collate_fn_map=collate_fn_map) for samples in transposed]
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Work\ml-project-1\ml_proj_env\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\collate.py", line 132, in collate
    return {key: collate([d[key] for d in batch], collate_fn_map=collate_fn_map) for key in elem}
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Work\ml-project-1\ml_proj_env\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\collate.py", line 132, in <dictcomp>
    return {key: collate([d[key] for d in batch], collate_fn_map=collate_fn_map) for key in elem}
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Work\ml-project-1\ml_proj_env\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\collate.py", line 155, in collate
    raise TypeError(default_collate_err_msg_format.format(elem_type))
TypeError: default_collate: batch must contain tensors, numpy arrays, numbers, dicts or lists; found <class 'NoneType'>
```

Which is weird because:

```py
any([x.__getitem__(i) == None for i in range(32)])
```

Returns `False`.

Comment: I've never used PyTorch, but FWIW, it might help to make a [mre] with complete but minimal code and the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341). And if you want more tips, check out [ask].

Comment: @wjandrea unfortunately, the data is proprietary. I believe it has something to do with having dictionary with variable data types as values being returned from `__getitem__()`. If somebody who knows PyTorch doesn't come along, I'll try to concoct a MRE.

Comment: I guess one of samples in your batch is None

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it. Apparently, some keys in the jsons had `None` value, `default_collate` doesn't like that.

Interestingly, while trying to create an MRE, I came up with this:

```py
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader


class testdataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        # generate a list of 10 dicts
        self.data = [{'a': str(i), 'b': i+1} for i in range(10)]
        self.labels = [{str(i): i} for i in range(10)]

    def __len__(self):
        return 10

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.data[idx], self.labels[idx]


test = testdataset()
x = DataLoader(test, batch_size=2)
for i, batch in enumerate(x):
    print(i)
```

Which ran into:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Work\ml-project-1\test.py", line 19, in <module>
    for i, batch in enumerate(x):
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Work\ml-project-1\ml_proj_env\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 628, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Work\ml-project-1\ml_proj_env\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 671, in _next_data
    data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Work\ml-project-1\ml_proj_env\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py", line 61, in fetch
    return self.collate_fn(data)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Work\ml-project-1\ml_proj_env\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\collate.py", line 271, in default_collate
    return collate(batch, collate_fn_map=default_collate_fn_map)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Work\ml-project-1\ml_proj_env\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\collate.py", line 147, in collate
    return [collate(samples, collate_fn_map=collate_fn_map) for samples in transposed]
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Work\ml-project-1\ml_proj_env\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\collate.py", line 147, in <listcomp>
    return [collate(samples, collate_fn_map=collate_fn_map) for samples in transposed]
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Work\ml-project-1\ml_proj_env\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\collate.py", line 129, in collate
    return elem_type({key: collate([d[key] for d in batch], collate_fn_map=collate_fn_map) for key in elem})
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Work\ml-project-1\ml_proj_env\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\collate.py", line 129, in <dictcomp>
    return elem_type({key: collate([d[key] for d in batch], collate_fn_map=collate_fn_map) for key in elem})
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Work\ml-project-1\ml_proj_env\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\collate.py", line 129, in <listcomp>
    return elem_type({key: collate([d[key] for d in batch], collate_fn_map=collate_fn_map) for key in elem})
KeyError: '0'
```

Changing the labels to be a list like so:
 `self.labels = [[str(i), i+1] for i in range(10)]`

Resolved the issue. I was almost misled into thinking that labels are expected to be lists which led me to play around with the labels, which eventually led to the solution.